# Integrate Ansible with Stackstorm WebUI

Tags: command-line

I am trying to integrate Ansible with StackStorm and I got stuck. 
I did all the steps required to install StackStorm and WebUI, on Ubuntu 16.04, the ones that may be found in the link above, on the official site:

[Steps to install StackStorm and WebUI](https://docs.stackstorm.com/install/deb.html#a-note-on-security)

---

I did the configuration part between StackStorm and WebUI, although I might not understand exactly what I should write down in the st2.conf, for the allow_origin :

```
[api]
# Host and port to bind the API server.
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 9101
logging = /etc/st2/logging.api.conf
mask_secrets = True
# allow_origin is required for handling CORS in st2 web UI.
# allow_origin =    http://myhost1.example.com:3000,http://myhost2.example.com:3000
allow_origin = http://webui.example.com
```

Instead of: **http://webui.example.com**  I wrote : **https://localhost/**, but I don't know if I write the right thing.

[Configuration WebUI](https://docs.stackstorm.com/install/config/webui.html)

---

The next steps were the installation of Ansible. 
I installed the packs core:

```
$st2 pack list
$st2 pack get core
```

and searched in the Packs section, after that, for Ansible and clicked on the install button. I attached photos:

[image: install ansible -first attempt]

You may see exactly where it got error: 
¬the *download pack* step was successfully checked, 
¬the  *make a pre-run* step was completed, 
¬while the last part : *install pack dependencies* got the status: Failed.

[image: Ansible-x attempt]

---

I even tried to manually install it, with the below command:

```
$sudo st2 pack install ansible
```

and got the same error:

[image: install ansible manually]

What am I doing wrong?
How should I install Ansible using StackStorm?